# C# winform : progress bar index was out of range

Tags: c#, winforms, list, progress-bar

i need to write 27 line of string into notepad. and my `progressbar1` used to count current line that being processed

```
void WriteOutput(string dir, List<String>listeksnya)
    {
        string outputdirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(textBox1.Text);
        string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(textBox1.Text);
        string filenameextension = Path.GetFileName(textBox1.Text);
        string newfilename = outputdirectory + "\\[Pichernenko.web.id] Output - " + filenameextension;            
        progressBar1.Maximum = listeksnya.Count;

        //MessageBox.Show("minimum is "+progressBar1.Minimum.ToString()+" maximum is "+progressBar1.Maximum);
        try
        {
            streamwriternya = new StreamWriter(newfilename);

            for (int i = 0; i < progressBar1.Maximum+1; i++)
            {                    
                MessageBox.Show(listeksnya.ElementAt(i));
                progressBar1.Value = i; 
            }                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            cmd.cetakGagal(ex.ToString());                                
        }            
    }
```

i don't write to notepad, because there's a error in my `progressbar` , it said `index was out of range`

i have set the maximum value of `progressbar` and i want to `progressbar` is filled completely while `MessageBox.Show(listeksnya.ElementAt(i));` processed the last element.

how do i resolve this ?

[image]

update :

i've found the answer by changing the following line

```
progressBar1.Maximum = listeksnya.Count-1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your termination condition of the `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < progressBar1.Maximum+1; i++)
```

Which makes you access the list's element up to `progressBar1.Maximum` (likely `100`) while you only have 27 elements and thus producing out of range error.

Note also that `C#` indexing starts from `0`, thus if you have `10` items in the list, you could get the element from index 0 to index **9**, not from index 0 to index **10** (which makes it having **11** elements instead of **10**)

```
 MessageBox.Show(listeksnya.ElementAt(i)); //will be error from i = 27 onwards
```

If you want to show the progress bar as many as the file numbers which have been processed, try to normalize the value:

```
for (int i = 0; i < progressBar1.Maximum+1; i++)
{                    
    MessageBox.Show(listeksnya.ElementAt(i));
    double val = (i + 1) * 100d / listeksnya.Count; //note the d to avoid 
    progressBar1.Value = (int)val; //this is correct now, cast to int if necessary
}
```

And note that you have to set your loop termination as many as `listeksnya.Count` element instead of following the `progressBar1.Maximum`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listeksnya.Count; ++i)
```

Comment: and that apply with those `List<String>listeksnya` also ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Actually the problem seems to be caused by it. Where do you get the error from?

Comment: but my `Progressbar1.Maximum` is set to `Listeks.count` , so their value must be equal, right ?